# Block user input only in CMD

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Is there a way to **block user input** (mouse and keyboard) **only in cmd/batch file**? 
I want to **avoid accidental pause or finish** for commands that are running.

Thanks.

Comment: If there isn't any user input, start it minimized.

Comment: What if every computer virus on Earth have such code....